# Unable to install asterisk on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, dpkg, asterisk

I am working on a openbts project.
I tried to install asterisk on 12.10 by watching a video.
But it is showing that it is not able to unlock a 'lock' file. in 
    `var/lib/dpkg/lock`
So i wanted some help on how to go about the installation of `asterisk` on ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After this, retry the installation